# Should security canaries be short?

Tags: buffer-overflow

I had an exam question on why security canaries should be short. I suspect that is so that the attacker has a harder time finding the canary. Is that right?

Comment: Why do you think it's harder to find (brute force?) a short canary?

Comment: I would think that you would want a security canary to be **easy** for an attacker to find, not hard.  But then again maybe I am misunderstanding what you are talking about...

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you are referring to stack canaries, which is a runtime construct and trivial to find. You want them to be short for performance reasons as they are compared every time a function returns.

You can find some more information of the performance of protection here: https://research.google/pubs/pub43809/